# File associations with Inno-Setup registry

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following in SwatchDogPRC.ISS:

```
(snip)
[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files\palmOne\Instapp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files\palmOne\Instaide.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files\palmOne\palmCmn.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files\palmOne\UserData.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[REGISTRY]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".prc"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "SwatchDogPRC"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue

Root: HKCR; Subkey: "SwatchDogPRC"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "SwatchDog Prog"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "SwatchDogPRC\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\Instapp.EXE,0"
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "SwatchDogPRC\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\Instapp.EXE"" ""%1"""
```

I'm trying to associate .prc files with Instapp.exe.

My registry entries are being read because the icon changes in File Explorer, and the program type changes as well.
But the program that is run when I double click on the .prc file hasn't changed.

Comment: in which windows version(s) are this happening?
Do you see your program listed in the sub-menu "open with..." of the contextual menu for that file in windows explorer? does this work if you use that menu to open the file with your program?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the ChangesAssociations=Yes in the [Setup] section.